# Not able to import FontAwesome_swift

Tags: ios, swift, font-awesome

This is the Podfile I am using

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'FontAwesome.swift'

then i m running $ pod install

In the view Controller,

import FontAwesome_swift   -- Error  no such module.

The terminal result  after pod install

$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories

Analyzing dependencies

Downloading dependencies

Using FontAwesome.swift (0.4.2)

Generating Pods project

Integrating client project

Sending stats

Comment: after you call install pod , do you check the result? because afaik , you should call , pod install.

Comment: Nope. How to check the result ?

Comment: after you type pod install to terminal  , are you sure cocoapods installed the library?

Comment: This is how its coming $ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using FontAwesome.swift (0.4.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats

Comment: sometimes cocoapods even installs the pod but it's not updated in xcode , have you tried re-opening xcode?

Comment: my final comment will be try to do it live import "FontAwesome" without ".swift" if that does not work , try using without import ^_^

Comment: Nope. still not working